# Laravel BadMethodCallException Method getLogin does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am in the process of upgrading a CMS that was built on Laravel 5.1 to Laravel 5.5. I am getting the following error.

> BadMethodCallException  Method [getLogin] does not exist. in
>   Controller.php (line 68)
>   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php

Here are my routes. Any idea what is the issue?

```
Http\routes.php
Route::get('core/admin/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('core/admin/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('core/admin/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
```

Comment: Look in your `AuthController` for a `getLogin` method.

Answer (score 2):

This is solved. I simply added the following method to the AuthController.php.

```
public function getLogin()
{
    if (view()->exists('auth.authenticate')) {
        return view('auth.authenticate');
    }

    return view('auth.login');
}
```